# How to restore a state in alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco-share

I was working on a project which uses alfresco to maintain the content.
I am looking for the ways to take the backup of the data.
I am aware that alf_data is the directory which has all the data and its databases file that is associated with it.

Some times when i try to restore the data by replacing the alf_data and database(sql files) the system becomes unstable and dont shows the users and all.

Also i am not sure about which log file i can check to know the errors.
or if there is another way to take the backup of current state and restoring it.

Comment: Are you doing the backup when alfresco is down? You also need to recreate the index in solr, or lucene if you are in an old version. The process to backup and restore is not complex and it has to work as it is described in the alfresco documentation

Comment: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ch-backup-restore.html

Comment: No , alfresco was in running state when i took the backup. also i have no idea about indexing in solr I am using alfresco 4.2.e, can you please provide a bit detailed information.Thanks.@MarcoAltieri

Comment: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/backup-intro.html this is for version 4.2

Comment: The cold backup is easier. Backup the solr index as described in the doc and then stop alfresco.

Comment: If your repository is not big, you can also recreate the solr index after the restore so you do not need to back up the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to correctly backup your system, there is 3 different things to backup :

- The database (a dump of your DB should do)
- The files (contentstore and contentstore.deleted from your alf_data)
- The indexes (it may differ depending on your index engine)

In case of hot backup (backup the system while it is running), there is some risk of some incoherence between these three components. Therefore, the process should be done in the exact order explained in [the docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/tasks/backup-hot.html) to avoid any data loss!

Comment: I tried this and got the backup's of Database and alf_data as well as the indexes.......i am using solr . But even after restoring these , i am unable to see the data in the program.

Comment: Have you done solr backup as instructed in [here](https://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/solr-backup-recovery.html)

Comment: I have .........i did it in this location
/opt/alfresco-4.2.e/alf_data/solrBackup/alfresco/snapshot.20160213020001/_l8.fdt    ....also many similar files were created